# Mercurial EncodeDecodeFilter tempfile template not picking up my OUTFILE from sed batch

Tags: mercurial, sed, mercurial-hook

I am currently being ruthlessly disabused of the simple, and seemingly necessary premise that if you follow the docs, things will work as advertized. While I do understand that this is not always the case, lately I have been plagued by a torrent of such WTFs.

The first thing that will make the snipers happy is, yes, this has to do with hg keywords. Specifically, ensuring they are always shrunk before a commit. I have discovered that a precommit hook of `hg kwshrink` will not work because hg has a lock on the directory, so the next candidate is an `[encode]` filter.

```
[encode]
#1 **.cs = sed -e "s/\$Date.*\$/\$Date\$/g"
#2 **.cs = tempfile: C:\batch\hg-kwshrink.bat INFILE OUTFILE
```

I started with #2, but #1 doesn't work either, and my batch is simply

```
sed -e "s/\$Date.*\$/\$Date\$/g" %1 > %2
rem sed -e "s/\$Date.*\$/\$Date\$/g" %1 > %1.tmp
rem echo %1 >>C:\temp\sed1.txt
rem echo %2 >>C:\temp\sed2.txt
rem copy %1.tmp C:\temp\sed3.txt
rem copy %1.tmp %2 /y
```

with the rems showing my investigations.

It appears everything is happening correctly EXCEPT hg is not using my output, it simply commits the original file as if it never read the docs on how it should behave.

Evidently I am missing a magic incantation or need to reassess my choice of career here.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
sed -e "s/\\$Date.*\\$/\\$Date\\$/g"
```

or

```
sed -e 's/\$Date.*\$/\$Date\$/g'
```

the \ is substitued by between double quote normaly